# Decrypt byte array in Java

Tags: java, c#, arrays

My question is about C# and Java.

I want to decrypt a byte array like the method d67 of C# from the following link: https://github.com/AresChat/cb0t/blob/master/cb0t/Misc/Hashlink.cs

I translated it to Java:

```
private static byte[] d67(byte[] data, int b)
    {
        byte[] buffer = new byte[data.length];
        System.arraycopy(data, 0, buffer, 0, data.length);

        for (int i = 0; i < data.length; i++)
        {
            buffer[i] = (byte)(data[i] ^ b >> 8 & 255);
            b = (b + data[i]) * 23219 + 36126 & 65535;
        }
        return buffer;
    }
```

But it gives me not the same result as the C# method.

What did I translate wrong?

The result I am getting with C#:

```
public static void Main() 
        {
           string str = "F5fPxdTq8eJeuqSVejGmq7aTh6BJZ8J0jgt92MDDjxTIWf+mWa8Ld+01L2bVIV6FXhCO";
      byte[] val2 = Convert.FromBase64String(str);
      val2 = d67(val2, 28435);
      Console.WriteLine("Converted byte value: {0}", BitConverter.ToString(val2));
        }
private static byte[] d67(byte[] data, int b)
        {
            byte[] buffer = new byte[data.Length];
            Array.Copy(data, buffer, data.Length);

            for (int i = 0; i < data.Length; i++)
            {
                buffer[i] = (byte)(data[i] ^ b >> 8 & 255);
                b = (b + data[i]) * 23219 + 36126 & 65535;
            }
            return buffer;
        }
```

are:
78-9C-63-60-C0-04-CE-1E-8E-21-40-EC-E7-E7-EA-C3-60-A6-76-C9-DC-F0-0A-48-D4-D7-31-D2-3F-C8-35-58-C1-C5-55-C1-D8-40-C7-C4-40-C7-D4-80-81-01-00-F3-11-09-F1

I am expecting the same result with Java:

```
public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        String encodedString = "arlnk://F5fPxdTq8eJeuqSVejGmq7aTh6BJZ8J0jgt92MDDjxTIWf+mWa8Ld+01L2bVIV6FXhCO";
        encodedString = encodedString.substring(8);
        Base64.Decoder decoder = Base64.getDecoder();
        byte[] decodedByteArray = decoder.decode(encodedString);
        decodedByteArray = d67(decodedByteArray, 28435);
        String array = "";
        for (int f=0; f<decodedByteArray.length; f++) {
            if (f == decodedByteArray.length - 1) {
                array = array + String.format("%02X", decodedByteArray[f]);
            }
            else {
                array = array + String.format("%02X", decodedByteArray[f]) + "-";
            }
        }
        System.out.print(array);
    }

    private static byte[] d67(byte[] data, int b)
    {
        byte[] buffer = new byte[data.length];
        System.arraycopy(data, 0, buffer, 0, data.length);

        for (int i = 0; i < data.length; i++)
        {
            buffer[i] = (byte)(data[i] ^ b >> 8 & 255);
            b = (b + data[i]) * 23219 + 36126 & 65535;
        }
        return buffer;
    }
```

Comment: what is the result, you are expecting, vs the result you get

Comment: Here's an observation: The Java `byte` type is signed. The C# `byte` type is unsigned.

Comment: I updated the post to show you what I am getting and what expecting.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As @khelwood observation `byte` type is different in both languages.

You can convert signed to unsigned.

After converting the Signed byte to unsigned it produces the result same as in .Net

```
    private static byte[] d67(byte[] data, int b) {
        byte[] buffer = new byte[data.length];
        System.arraycopy(data, 0, buffer, 0, data.length);

        for (int i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
            int unsignedData = unsignedToBytes(data[i]);

            buffer[i] = (byte) (unsignedData ^ b >> 8 & 255);

            b = (b + unsignedData) * 23219 + 36126 & 65535;
        }
        return buffer;
    }

    public static int unsignedToBytes(byte b) {
        return b & 0xFF;
    }
```

Comment: Oh, my God!! I just had to convert it to unsigned bytes!! You can not imagine how much I thank you!! Thanks for saving my day!!!!!